# Counting in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

```
A,B,C,D
X1,desc,may 1, 1
X2,desc, june 5, 1
Y,desc, dec 8, 2
Y,desc, jan 4, 3
```

I want to look at X1, X2, and Y. And sum so that the dataframe looks as follows:

```
A,B 
X1,1
X2,1
Y,5
```

So for all instances of X1 we sum them, same for X2 and Y. Is there a useful pandas function for this that I don't know about? I know a really bad solution where I could just extract everything into lists and see if it is present and then sum that way and turn it back into a dataframe, but I'm not sure if there is a better method to do this all with pandas. Essentially it is like an aggregate.

Comment: Take a look at `groupby.sum()` function.

Comment: ah ok thanks! You can groupby column A and then use a sum on it

Comment: But if A is the index how would this work? I can't call df['A']

Comment: If that is the case, you can either supply `df.index` or `level=0` to the `Groupby` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column to group by is set as the index as is the case here:

```
       B      C      D
   A            
   X1  desc   may    1
   X2  desc   june   1
   Y   desc   dec    2
   Y   desc   jan    3
```

Simply use a group by index as below:

```
df1.groupby([df1.index]).D.sum()
```

Which yields the desired result:

```
A
X1    1
X2    1
Y     5
Name: D, dtype: int64
```